# Pass a constant name to another method

Tags: ruby

I have read about sending method names as parameters in ruby, however in my case I want to allow the user to select a Digest format and use the answer to set the digest type:

```
def hash_digest(file, argument)
    format = Digest::argument.new  #using the argument here

    ...

end

hash_digest(filename, :MD5)
```

I have tried:

```
def hash_digest(file, argument)
    format = Digest::send(argument).new 
    ...
end

hash_digest(filename, :MD5)
```

But I get a no method `md5' error, despite MD5 being a valid algorithm in the Digest method.  The exact error is:

```
send': undefined method MD5' for Digest:Module (NoMethodError) –
```

Is this possible in ruby?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: You're probably right, I thought I'd see if anyone had any nifty tricks!

Comment: `Digest.const_get(:MD5).new`

Comment: You try to call `:MD5` and provided error contain `md5`. Provide error exactly.

Comment: fileDigest.rb:18:in `public_send': undefined method `MD5' for Digest:Module (NoMethodError)

Comment: Your question is unclear. First off, I don't understand how you are getting an error referring to `md5` when you are passing in `:MD5` as an argument. You *should* be getting an error related to `MD5`, *iff* you get an error at all. Secondly, you ask "is this possible in ruby", but the error message *proves* that it is possible. Your code is working 100% correctly. The problem is that there is no method named `md5` defined in `Digest`'s singleton class, but that is a completely different problem that has nothing to do with your question. You ask whether it is possible to dynamically call a …

Comment: … a method in Ruby, and the fact that you are getting a `NoMethodError` *does* in fact show that you *are* dynamically calling a method … so what's your actual question?

Comment: I actually think this is a good question for people who'd like to know how to do this, so it's a real shame that it got down voted.

Comment: @jörg, If you want to brush up on the methods and algorithms available in the Digest method, here is a link. ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest.html MD5 is listed in there and as the answer shows (thanks heaps for the people who actually tried to help and had no problem understanding the question) calling Digest::MD5.new is totally valid.  The question has been answered, I think the answer shows pretty clearly what I was trying to do.

Comment: The link you posted is for the `Digest` module. But in your question you are asking about "the Digest method", so the link you posted clearly is not relevant. And even if it were relevant, it also clearly shows that there is *no* method named `MD5` nor `md5`. There is a *constant* named `MD5`, but that is not what you are asking about: "Pass part of a method name to another method". Also, how is anybody supposed to know *what* `Digest` you are talking about? How do I know you are not talking about [this](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Digest.html)?

Comment: The fact that you are telling me to read the answer to figure out what the question is, means that the information in the question doesn't accurately reflect the problem. I still don't understand whether you are talking about methods or constants, for example. The question mentions "methods" multiple times, and there is no mention of constants anywhere, yet the answer is only about constants. This question is not helpful at all to people who want to know about dynamically calling methods (which is what the question asks), and thus is rightfully downvoted.

Comment: @jörg, the questions been answered.  Are you just trying to tell everyone how smart you are or are you interested in helping me?  Everyone else understood.  Get a grip bud.  Unfortunately things like this make this website an unattractive place for users who may not know every single correct piece of syntax and are trying to build their knowledge.  I am sure you can be very helpful.  This episode is pointless.  You could have suggested an edit to help me phrase the question better,, you could have just figured it out like everyone else and posted an answer, or you could just go on a rant...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141354/discussion-between-ryan-murphy-and-jorg-w-mittag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this works:

```
require 'digest'

def hash_digest(file, digest_algorithm)
    format = Digest.const_get(digest_algorithm).new
end

hash_digest('test', 'SHA256')
```

Also since the number of options is fairly small you could always just use a `case` statement:

```
require 'digest'

def hash_digest(file, digest_algorithm)
    format = case digest_algorithm
             when 'HMAC'   then Digest::HMAC.new 
             when 'MD5'    then Digest::MD5.new 
             when 'RMD160' then Digest::RMD160.new
             when 'SHA1'   then Digest::SHA1.new  
             when 'SHA256' then Digest::SHA256.new 
             when 'SHA384' then Digest::SHA384.new
             when 'SHA512' then Digest::SHA512.new  
             end
end

hash_digest('test', 'SHA256')
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get: /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/digest.rb:16:in `const_missing': library not found for class Digest::Digest -- digest/digest (LoadError)

Comment: Yeah, that was the other option, I was really just wondering out loud if it was possible.

Comment: You were right the first time, I made a typo, fixed the typo and it worked.  Thanks for that!

Comment: Or, for the second option, you can use a hash as well.